# dbt ref() vs source()

Tags: postgresql, dbt

I’m trying to make one model in dbt depend on another (trying to run the second model after the first one is completely finished), but I’m confused, when to use `ref()` or `source()`?

What is the difference between them?

Comment: These docs will help: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/ref and https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/source

Answer (score 20):

Using `ref` creates the lineage for your DAG and will run the predecessor models. Using `source` references a base table that is not necessarily a model. Rule of thumb is use `source` in your base models and everything else should use `ref`.

Example - Green nodes represent tables ingested into your DWH. The blue/red nodes are DBT models.
[image]